# Riemann-Roch space related to a multiple of Drinfeld divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Considering a smooth projective curve $X$ over $L\supseteq \mathbb{F}_q$ of genus $g$, where $q = p^m$ is a prime power. Let $W\in X^{(d)}(L)$ be an effective divisor of degree $d$ with $h^1(W) = 0$. Suppose further that $\infty\notin \operatorname{Supp}(W)$. We know that $h^0(W-(d-g+1)\infty)\geq 0$. I am wondering for what kind of $W$, we have $h^0(W-(d-g+1)\infty) = 0$.

In particular, what I am actually considering is that so-called Drinfeld divisor $V$ of degree $g$, with $V^{(1)}-V+\xi-\infty$ principal, where $\xi,\infty\in X(L)$, $\xi\neq \infty^{(s)}$ for all $-g\leq s\leq g$, and $V^{(1)}$ is the Frobenius twist of $V$. By Drinfeld's lemma, we know $h^0(V-\infty) = h^1(V-\infty) = 0$ and $h^0(V) = 1$. I am wondering if we have $h^0(nV-(ng-g+1)\infty) = 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, which is clear for $n=1$.